# change data type to float or numpy float

Tags: python, numpy

I want my def variable gives out float or numpy float the type.

Here is my solution:

```
def answer_deg(xyz_file):
    file = open('cysteine.xyz','r')
    coords = file.readlines()[2:]
    file.close()

    #S-C bond: vectors and lengths
    x_sc=float(coords[7].split()[1])-float(coords[6].split()[1])
    y_sc=float(coords[7].split()[2])-float(coords[6].split()[2])                                      
    z_sc=float(coords[7].split()[3])-float(coords[6].split()[3])
    sc = [x_sc,y_sc,z_sc]
    sc_length = sqrt(x_sc**2 + y_sc**2 + z_sc**2)

    #S-H bond: vectors and lengths
    x_sh=float(coords[7].split()[1])-float(coords[11].split()[1])
    y_sh=float(coords[7].split()[2])-float(coords[11].split()[2])                                      
    z_sh=float(coords[7].split()[3])-float(coords[11].split()[3])
    sh = [x_sh,y_sh,z_sh]
    sh_length = sqrt(x_sh**2 + y_sh**2 + z_sh**2)

    #S-C-H valence angle
    theta = acos(np.dot(sc, sh)/(sc_length*sh_length))
    theta_deg = np.degrees(theta)
    
    return round(theta_deg, 2)

print(answer_deg('cysteine.xyz'))
print(type(answer_deg))
```

This solution will print out:

```
print(answer_deg('cysteine.xyz')) = 96.47
print(type(answer_deg)) = <class 'function'>
```

I don't intend type(answer_deg) to gives out 'function' as its types. Do you know where I'm wrong or where I should amend so that it will print float or np.float as its types?

Comment: `answer_deg` says it's a function **because it is a function**. If you want to print the type of `96.47` to see if it's a float, you need to `print(type(answer_deg('cysteine.xyz')))`

Comment: This `print(type(answer_deg))` gives the function type, not the return value’s type.

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker got it, thanks!

Comment: @S3DEV ah, got it, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can force the answer_deg to be of type:float by using the following print(float(answer_deg('cysteine.xyz'))) .

Comment: The `float` conversion (if required) should be done *inside* the function, not after.  That’s just asking for issues later.